# UICollectionView with Infinitescrolling not update content size

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, infinite-scroll

I have the following problem, when I load more data and I scroll down works perfectly but once I'm going up, the scrolling starts to stutter. I look at the scrolling bar size and it's not getting an update, and when I start to go up it's getting resized and provoke this behavior

```
{
       viewModel.state.rewards.subscribe(onNext: { (rewards) in

        UIView.performWithoutAnimation {
            //self.collectionView.reloadData()
            rewards?.rewards?.enumerated().map({ (index, reward) in
                if index < self.collectionView.numberOfItems(inSection: 0) {
                    print("GOT IT", reward.name)
                } else {
                    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
                        self.collectionView.performBatchUpdates({ () -> Void in
                            self.collectionView.setContentOffset(self.collectionView.contentOffset, animated: false)
                            self.collectionView.insertItems(at: [IndexPath(row: index, section: 0)])
                            self.collectionView.invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
                        }, completion: nil)
                    } else {
                        // Fallback on earlier versions
                        self.collectionView.performBatchUpdates({ () -> Void in
                            self.collectionView.setContentOffset(self.collectionView.contentOffset, animated: false)
                            self.collectionView.insertItems(at: [IndexPath(row: index, section: 0)])
                            self.collectionView.invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
                        })
                    }

                }
            })
        }

    }).disposed(by: disposeBag)
}
```

I try with invalidate layout, invalidate intrinsicContentSize but don't work. Any idea?

Thanks!